# Maintaining custom file extension in Internet Explorer when using PHP to send file?

Tags: php

I have a server-side zip archive that I would like to pass along as a download. I'm using a custom extension to associate these specific archives with some client software (e.g. CustomArchive.bwz).

Chrome and FireFox handle this custom extension perfectly, but Internet Explorer keeps tacking ".zip" at the end of the file name (e.g. CustomArchive.bwz.zip).

Here is my download file method:

```
function downloadFile($file)
{
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
```

As an example, I am calling it like this:

```
downloadFile( "CustomArchive.bwz" );
```

Where CustomArchive.bwz is simply a zip file with a custom extension.

After playing with removing various bits from my downloadFile method, I was able to narrow it down to my calling ob_clean(). Unfortunately, removing that call causes the downloads to be corrupted.

Is there a work around that I can force IE to use the .bwz extension and not tack on .zip?

My server is running PHP 5.3.5 on IIS 7.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From marcelebrate: using `application/force-download` instead of `application/octet-stream` is what prevented IE from assuming my file was a zip archive.

```
function downloadFile($file){
    $file_name = $file;
    $mime = 'application/force-download';

    header('Pragma: public');   // required
    header('Expires: 0');       // no cache
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Cache-Control: private',false);
    header('Content-Type: '.$mime);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file_name).'"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Connection: close');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

    //from Christian Sciberras: There may (often) be multiple levels of output buffering.
    while(ob_get_level()) ob_end_clean();
    ob_implicit_flush(true);

    readfile($file_name);       // push it out
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Changing my Content-Type header to "application/force-download" as your solution above does, did the trick. I had to keep the ob_clean() and flush() calls in there though, or the downloaded zip archive would be corrupted.

Comment: +1 The `application/force-download` is what I've been using to get this working... Though I don't understand why the two lines, `ob_clean()` and `flush()` are needed. First of, add a `Content-Length` header, secondly, people usually terminate buffers before output, ie: `while(ob_get_level())ob_end_clean(); ob_implicit_flush(true);`.

Comment: Thank you both for the input/answers. @Christian: What's the difference between your while loop and the ob_clean/flush sequence? After running into troubles with my own simplified script, I lifted the internals for my downloadFile() method from the readfile example in the PHP documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) and it worked a charm. The ob_clean/flush sequence is what wound up making the difference—minus the MIME issue of this question.

Comment: @marcelebrate - There may (often) be multiple levels of output buffering.

Comment: @Chrstian: Ah, good to know. @kradmiy: It might be worth updating the answer to include Christian's changes, and maybe call out before the function code block what, specifically, answered the question: using `application/force-download` instead of `application/octet-stream` is what prevented IE from assuming my file was a zip archive.